# summation of multiples of 5 to a given target

Tags: java, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java : Summation of `multiples of 5` in a group to a given target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977113/java-summation-of-multiples-of-5-in-a-group-to-a-given-target)

Hi SO People,

I'm struggling to get the below problem working with no approach in right direction.

Write a java function such that given an array of ints, is it possible to choose a group of some of the ints, such that the group sums to the given target with these additional constraints: all multiples of 5 in the array must be included in the group. If the value immediately following a multiple of 5 is 1, it must not be chosen.

- groupSum5(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 19) → true
- groupSum5(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 17) → true
- groupSum5(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 12) → false
- groupSum5(0, {3, 5, 1}, 5) → true
- groupSum5(0, {3, 5, 1}, 4) → false

The function siganture is public boolean groupSum5(int start, int[] nums, int target)

I have written the partial code but there are failing test cases for the same.

```
     public boolean groupSum5(int start, int[] nums, int target) {     
           start = 0;     
           boolean flag = false;     
           for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){     
             if(nums[i]%5==0){     
                  start+=nums[i];                   
             }else if((start != target) && (start%5==0)){     
                  start+=nums[i];       
             }else if(start == target){      
                  flag = true;      
                  return flag;     
             }else if((nums[i]%5==0) && (nums[i+1]==1)){      
                  continue;                
             }    
           }
            return flag;      
     }
```

All the test cases are failing even after writing this code.
Im struggling to get this rite for a long time.

EDIT for DIANTE:Could you provide me with the code fix since i have tried this much and i dont know how to proceed

Comment: Please post a specific question, rather than a generic "help me".

Comment: please don't edit other people's posts to send them messages. :) Please note that you don't need 50 reputation points for _all_ comments, just ones where you're not directly involved already: ["you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you’ve asked, even with 1 rep."](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation-abilities)

Comment: also, while we like helping people with homework problems,  we avoid giving homework answers -- it is a problem for you to solve and struggle with. You've posted a start, and that's good :) but if you carefully re-read @Dante's post, I think you'll find it is an excellent starting point. @UBM's suggestion is a good one, but if [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) is a new term for you, then don't worry about it yet. You'll get there next year. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a solution, **but see discussion after**:

```
package so5987154;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

public class Summation {
    /**
     * Sum of start and every element of the collection.
     * 
     * @param start
     *            starting value for the sum
     * @param list
     *            Collection to sum.
     * @return the sum.
     */
    private int sum(final Integer start, final Collection<Integer> list) {
        int sum = start;

        for (final int i : list) {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * Given an array of ints, is it possible to choose a group of some of the ints, such that the group sums to the given target
     * with these additional constraints: all multiples of 5 in the array must be included in the group. If the value immediately
     * following a multiple of 5 is 1, it must not be chosen.
     * 
     * @param start
     *            not used
     * @param nums
     *            array of int (input)
     * @param target
     *            target value for the summation
     * @return true if we found a group that meet the criteria.
     */
    public boolean groupSum5(final int start, final int[] nums, final int target) {
        // list of values that need to be included (multiple of 5)
        final List<Integer> fixed = Lists.newArrayList();

        // list of value that can be included (anything but 1 preceded by a multiple of 5)
        final List<Integer> candidates = Lists.newArrayList();

        // fills candidates and fixed
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            final int cand = nums[i];

            if (cand == 1 && i > 0) {
                final int prev = nums[i - 1];
                if (prev % 5 != 0) {
                    candidates.add(cand);
                }
            } else if (cand % 5 == 0) {
                fixed.add(cand);
            } else if (cand <= target) {
                candidates.add(cand);
            }
        }

        // compute the sum of fixed
        final int sumFixed = sum(0, fixed);

        // if the sum of fixed is equals to target we don't need to do anything because
        // we already know we need to return true.
        if (sumFixed == target) {
            return true; // NOPMD
        }

        // if the sum of fixed is greater than target we don't need to do anything because
        // we already know we need to return false (all multiple of 5 must be included)
        // If candidates is empty there's no way we can achieve the desired goal.
        if (sumFixed <= target && !candidates.isEmpty()) {
            // generates all subsets of candidates:
            // { 1, 2 } => {}, {1}, {2}, {1, 2}
            final Set<Set<Integer>> powerSet = Sets.powerSet(Sets.newHashSet(candidates));

            // for each found subset, computes the sum of the subset and add it to the sum of
            // multiples of 5 then compare it to target. If equals => return true.
            for (final Set<Integer> set : powerSet) {
                if (sumFixed + sum(0, set) == target) {
                    return true; // NOPMD
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Associated test:

```
package so5987154.tests;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Test;

import so5987154.Summation;

@SuppressWarnings("PMD")
public class SummationTest {
    private final Summation s = new Summation();

    @Test
    public void testGroupSum5() {
        assertTrue(s.groupSum5(0, new int[] { 2, 5, 10, 4 }, 19));
        assertTrue(s.groupSum5(0, new int[] { 2, 5, 10, 4 }, 17));
        assertFalse(s.groupSum5(0, new int[] { 2, 5, 10, 4 }, 12));
        assertTrue(s.groupSum5(0, new int[] { 2, 5, 10, 4 }, 19));
        assertTrue(s.groupSum5(0, new int[] { 3, 5, 1 }, 5));
        assertFalse(s.groupSum5(0, new int[] { 3, 5, 1 }, 4));
        assertTrue(s.groupSum5(0, new int[] { 3, 1 }, 4));
        assertFalse(s.groupSum5(0, new int[] { 3, 1 }, 2));
        assertTrue(s.groupSum5(0, new int[] { 1 }, 1));
    }
}
```

BUT, your signature parameter `start` suggest something with recursion. In a first step, you could remove from the array of ints:

- all multiple of 5 and sum those into start
- all 1 preceded by a multiple of 5

then call you method with start and the new array of int.

In the method, you need to:

- test if start is equals to target => return true
- test if start is over target => return false
- test if array is empty => return false
- call the method with start + x where x is an element of the array and array with x removed => return OR of all the result

Example: { 2, 5, 10, 4 }, target = 19

sum of multiple of 5: 5+10 = 15, no 1 preceded by 5 => new array { 2, 4 }

*first call*: `method(15, {2, 4}, 19)`

- start == target => NO
- start > target => NO
- array empty => NO
- r1 = method(15+2, {4}, 19) and r2 = method(15+4, {2}, 19)

*second call (r1)*: `method(15+2, {4}, 19)`

- start == target => NO
- start > target => NO
- array empty => NO
- r11 = method(15+2+4, {}, 19)

*third call (r11)*: `method(15+2+4, {}, 19)`

- start == target => NO
- start > target => YES => **false**

*second call (r2)*: `method(15+4, {2}, 19)`

- start == target => YES => **true**

we are back in the first call with `r1 = r11 = false` and `r2 = true` => `return false OR true = true`, END

*You can see that `Sets.powerSet` is equivalent to the recursive call r(k)*

Comment: in case i have clarifications i will come back to u

Comment: i dont want to use the below 2 imports.any workarounds `import com.google.common.collect.Lists;` `import com.google.common.collect.Sets;` any workaround using the existing java collection framework

Comment: No, you need to code something following the explanation I made, in "homework" there's "work" ;)

Comment: i have made changes for list and its working ,but hopefully if you provide an aleternative for `import com.google.common.collect.Sets;` it will be appreciated.

Comment: any workaround using the existing java collection framework for Sets and Lists

Comment: `Lists.newArrayList()` can be replaced with `new ArrayList<E>()` and you don't need `Sets` if you code your own recursive method.

Comment: Its failing for one test scenario.`groupSum5(0, {1}, 1) → true` should return `true` but the code returns `false`